# How to change a application Default Icon in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I am using phone gap do build an application for multiple platform but I can't change the default icon can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Note that, at least for Android, if you're doing a **local build** the `config.xml` used in remote builds is ignored and the icon used is the one at `platforms/android/res/drawable`

For remote builds in multiple platforms you have information about how to set the icons in the `config.xml`file e.g. here:

**For the CLI:**
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html

**For PhoneGap Build:**
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/#icons

Comment: Awesome. This is what worked. config.xml in the www folder, configured to my needs. This should be listed as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Go in your project folder and you should see another folder called "icon" (in Your_Project_Name/Resources/icon, where your folder "Your_Project_Name" is in the same directory containing your folder "www").

You should find 3 default icons:

1. icon-72.png
2. icon.png
3. icon@2x.png

Add you icons there and replace the default ones.
Do not change the name of the files.

If you want to change the Launch images, just go in the folder "splash" (Your_Project_Name/Resources/splash) and replace the default images:

1. Default.png
2. Default@2x