# How to replace applicaton default icon on phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have developed a simple application using jquery mobile & phonegap. The problem is, unable to change the phonegap default icon. How can i do that for android?

Comment: Maybe this page help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329554/how-to-change-a-application-default-icon-in-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

By default, the icons are placed in `res/icon/android` folder for you to replace.