# How can I change the default icon in phonegap online build?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have developed some Android App, using https://build.phonegap.com online. But how can I change the default icon which is showing in my Android Phone after installing the application?

Comment: This has already been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329554/how-to-change-a-application-default-icon-in-phonegap

Comment: Yes, but it's not working. There was an option within the website  https://build.phonegap.com, in the "Settings" tab. But now I cant find it.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/ might come in handy...

Answer (score 0):

Get to your app root inside res folder change the icons. Try to mantain same names.